# pandoc: getCurrentDirectory:getWorkingDirectory: permission denied (Operation not permitted)

Tags: osx, debugging, markdown, pandoc, permissions

I'm trying to render the output of a markdown file using `C-c C-c p`. On doing so, a webpage opens on my browser displaying `pandoc: getCurrentDirectory:getWorkingDirectory: permission denied (Operation not permitted)`

How do I preview the file and prevent this error?